# Is a hard shutdown harmful to computer hardware?

Tags: power, shutdown, hardware-failure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a power failure or forceful shutdown damage hardware?](https://superuser.com/questions/103861/can-a-power-failure-or-forceful-shutdown-damage-hardware)

If I switch off my computer pressing the power button for five (5) seconds, can I break any of the components, damage it or make it work worse?

At first, I thought switching off my computer from the power button and from the power cord would be the same. My case was with the power cord, though.