# Windows 8 not booting at all

Tags: windows-8, boot, thinkpad

I am using a Lenovo ThinkPad Twist with Windows 8, and it isn't booting at all. It doesn't even show the Lenovo logo or anything. It makes no sound, nothing. It used to work. It stopped working after Action Center said to reboot because of a drive error. I rebooted the computer, but then my friend decided to randomly start typing on the keyboard and managed to cancel the shutdown. After that, it wouldn't log in so I held down the power button to force a shutdown. Now, it doesn't boot

Comment: Does it do literally nothing when you push the power button? If not, what exactly does it do?

Comment: nothing whatsoever

Comment: Remove the battery and disconnect power for ten minutes. Then replace the battery, reconnect power, and try again. If it still doesn't turn on, you have a hardware problem somewhere.

Comment: It is ultrabook no removable battery

Comment: I don't think that it is hardware issue because this happened after I forced shut it down, nothing like this has happened before, it is less than a year old, it is a lenovo computer, and action center had the error almost immediately before this happened

Comment: Also, action center said it is a disk problem so it should have at least said the lenovo boot screen and then generated an error instead of just staying black.\

Comment: Those are all symptoms of a hardware problem. It was working fine, you had an indication of a hardware error, and from then on the system was unable to initialize.

Comment: The indication, as you call it, was that there was a drive error. Even if the hard drive crashed completely, the computer should at least be able to do the POST and I should be able to hear some sounds/lights. Also, the battery cannot be broken of anything because when I plug it in a little green light signaling that it is charging turns on, and when I remove the charging cord it goes off, as usual. I think that the power button might be broken.

Comment: I also think it isn't hardware because it was working fine, and then I manually shut it down. as you can see from this superuser question (http://superuser.com/questions/103861/can-a-power-failure-or-forceful-shutdown-damage-hardware/), a forceful shutdown like what I did should not cause issues. I also shut it down by holding onto the power button for several seconds, and i might have pressed it too hard or something.

Comment: You said, "It stopped working after Action Center said to reboot because of a drive error".

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes works with PC's and some laptops (don't know about ultrabooks without the ability to remove the batter).
Hold the power button in for about 30 seconds. Release the button, take a deep breath, and try the power again.
Good Luck!

Comment: it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally got it fixed (I had a warranty), and they didn't tell me what the problem was exactly, but here's what I figured out: Lenovo Thinkpad Twists (and some other lenovo computers) come with a "Settings" application, and one of the things it lets you change is that "battery life saver" where it only charges the battery to 50%, and then holds it there to extend the batteries longevity. Well, the software f-ed up, and it completely stopped charging, even though it should have been holding it at 50%, so it ran down to almost 0%, and it didn't have enough power to boot again after shutting it down (and because it was plugged in, windows gave me no warnings beforehand because it assumes everything is ok with the battery if it's plugged in). Somehow, it booted up again after a few days, and I got rid of the software.