# What happens with a normal disk when you unplug power vs an SSD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, hardware-failure

We are using SSD's sata2 disks, but they often get corrupt.
I also see that users on their desktop, don't use the on off switch from the computer but use the main power-switch of their office room. This switch turns of everything, it was once thought of to reduce power in our offices that way.

I explained many times to first logoff windows 7 but people forget that frequently and so this results in corrupt SSD's,

I wonder would it be safer to use normal hard disks ?

My main doubt here is I am not sure if they would park their disk heads if power goes off.

Comment: If your user's refuse to shutdown your computers the correct way even with a mechanical drive data corruption will happen. Resolve the human element and the problem will solve itself.  Of course the solution is scheduled tasks that shutdown every computer and a timer that turns on/off the power for the room.

Comment: I agree. You are looking for a hardware solution to a non hardware problem. Either apply reason, a clue-bat or a 'oh, you forgot to shut down? I will fix that **tomorrow**, meanwhile please pick your nose and hope your projects finish on-time.`

Comment: I can repair a PC order new disks, but i cannt do that with people.
I just need to know if normal disks will get their heads into parking mode when a sudden power drops

Comment: @user613326 - did you see this question?http://superuser.com/questions/103861/can-a-power-failure-or-forceful-shutdown-damage-hardware

Comment: A cleverly hidden battery backup with a smooth shutdown failsafe would be a good solution if you can't reprogram the humans in the office. :)

Comment: Tp moses Sure i agree an UPS would be great, but people who do the money part dont agree on the costs.

@CarlB Indeed powersweeps are something to worry about too, but since only (various vendors) SSD drives get broken, i wonder if normal internal disks sold as laptop disks would automaticly (mechanical) park their heads.

Comment: *"would it be safer to use normal hard disks ?"*  No, dirty shutdowns will cause data corruption for both HDDs and SDDs.  Most HDDs will park the heads on loss of power.  One solution is to move the data from the PCs to central servers, and turn the PCs into networked terminals.

Comment: "It's hard to soar with eagles when you work with turkeys." Your problems will never be over, no matter what kind of drive you use. Let the equipment abuse speak for itself, break out a spreadsheet, keep tabs on the money being wasted by equipment failure and downtime and show that it's more expensive than the perceived power wastage.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, when idling a PC can still be performing tasks in the background that require disk access, indexing, AV scans, backups, etc. Also consider that when a PC is abruptly disconnected from the mains the PSU supplied voltages will drop in an uncontrolled manner, logic circuits don't like that. I have recent experience of this when my 70KVA UPS failed during a power outage in a facility containing nearly 200 PCs.

Comment: All it takes is a mangled write to an MFT that the journal cannot roll back. Data corruption is quite fun if it's not your data, you make the user pay for their impatience, impertinence and ignorance. And Ouch! That was a major show stopper...